# Range of the function $\sqrt[4]{1-\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x²}}}$

Tags: functions

I am trying to find definitions range for the function $\sqrt[4]{1-\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x²}}}$.

I tried to sloe it like this:
Because I know that in real number range under the sqrt I can not have a negative number, I made three equations, where I presumed that every part of the function that is under the root, needs to have solution that is bigger or equal to zero.
These are the equations:

$25-x²$ for this equation I got that solution is range form -5 to 5

$4-\sqrt{25-x²}$ for this equation I got that solution is range from -3 to 3

$1-\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x²}}$ for this equation I got that solution is range from -4 to 4

I tired to connect these results with "and" statment, and it does not fits, because the solution for this problem is range from -4 to 4, and I got that the solution is range from -3 to 3.

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hint: the **cubic** root function is defined *everywhere* on the real line.

Comment: The "intersection" strategy is good for expressions of the form $f(x)+g(x)$ or $f(x)g(x)$. I would work from outwards in. We want $\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x^2}}\le 1$. Equivalently, we want $4-\sqrt{25-x^2} \le 1^3$. Equivalently, we want $\sqrt{25-x^2} \ge 3$. Equivalently, we want $x^2\le 16$. By the way, what you call definitions range is often called *domain*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim

> $1-\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x²}}$ for this equation I got that solution is range from -4 to 4

is incorrect because the function $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is definet for any real $x$. See for example x=-1 you have: $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$ because $(-1)^3=-1$.

Comment: Dou you mean for the function $4-\sqrt{25-x²}$

Comment: The esence is on the part $\sqrt[3]{4-\sqrt{25-x²}}$